# Is there any GUI orchestration available to configure iptables on linux servers?

Tags: iptables, gui, nat

Is there any open source UI orchestration available to configure IPtables?

I have checked in the internet and found some open source firewall packages available but i need a tool which can allow us to do the iptables/ firewalld configurations via UI... Please help

Comment: I want a server to be act like a NAT box.I need to configure thousands of lines in iptable-config to NAT certain public IP to certain private IP with a specific port. i need to handover this box to some other team.it will be easy if we have GUI to do this task...Please help...

Comment: I found FirewallBuilder for this... Please suggest... Is there any better solution than this..?